# view controller pushed from tab in tabbar controller is not coming back when i press back button

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I'm very new to `iOS` i'm using `UITabBarController` which i have taken a class for it and in that i'm having two tabs for two tabs i have two `UINavigationControllers`

from tab1 i need to push to new `UIViewController`,when i push new `UIViewController` it is coming on tab1 and it is having tabbar in that view
and it is not getting their `UINavigation` properties like it has custom back button and custom action for back button

but it is not calling back button action ,when i press back button it is not getting back to respective tab

any help appreciated

Comment: Can you please add the code used for back action.

Comment: i just used [self.navigationController  popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: Does your navigationcontroller works properly?

Comment: yes it is getting back when i'm in to view controller where i called tabbar controller

Answer (score 0):

Call functions to hide the tabbar and show the navigation bar.
If cannot, embed UIViewController in UINavigationController.
If back button doesn't work, use a custom button.

Comment: no everything is set up properly if any navigation needed for new view how to set it and pass data thruogh navigation to view controller